# user dashboard errors out

Tags: wordpress, dashboard, user-dashboard

When a user tries logging in and viewing the user dashboard, the page errors out and shows the "You do not have permission to access this page" message. It is actually failing to render the rest of the page, spitting out:
{{
@import url(/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/css/civicrm.css);
@import url(/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/css/extras.css);

Sorry but we are not able to provide this at the moment.
You do not have permission to access this page

[Return to home page.](http://txmpa.org/)

function toggle( element ) {
var className = element.className;
if ( className == 'crm-accordion-wrapper collapsed crm-fatal-error-details-block')
{ element.className = 'crm-accordion-wrapper crm-fatal-error-details-block'; }
else
{ element.className = 'crm-accordion-wrapper collapsed crm-fatal-error-details-block'; }
}
}}

Comment: What CiviCRM version are you using? Does the logged in user role have the __Access Contact Dashboard__ permission set? To check it navigate to Administer - User and Permission - Permissions - Wordpress Access Control.

Comment: Using version 4.4.6

Comment: And how about the __Access Contact Dashboard__ permission, is it active for the user role is trying to access the page? I assume this is an old Civi install (4.4.6), has anything changed on the server, PHP/MySQL/Apache/NginX upgrades or any plugins you might have recently installed/updated? Is very difficult to help without any additional information.

Comment: You are correct, that was the issue.  Client changed a buncha settings without telling us.